# crashing when trying to save 4 mb mp4 file at local in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I want to implement rich media in Notification Service Extension, my code works fine for images. but when I pass an url for some 4 mb mp4 file it crashes. I've tested several methods for downloading and saving that file and realized that I get crash when trying to store downloaded mp4 as data. this is my code for downloading media:

```
private func downloadMedia(mediaURL: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL) -> ()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: mediaURL) else {
        return
    }

    let mediaExtension = url.pathExtension
    // mp4

    if mediaExtension.isEmpty {
        fatalError()
    }

    let supportedRichMediaTypes = ["aiff", "wav", "mp3", "mp4", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "mpeg", "mpg", "avi", "m4a", "m4v"]
    guard supportedRichMediaTypes.contains(mediaExtension) else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let fileName = self.randomString(length: 10) + ".\(mediaExtension)"

    guard let cashesURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let localURL = cashesURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    // approach 1 for downloading mp4 file
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        print("\(#line)")    // can't reach this line and I get crash without printing this

        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError()
        }

        do {
            try data.write(to: localURL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(localURL)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()

    // approach 2 for downloading mp4 file
    let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (downloadedURL, urlResponse, error) in

        if let downloadedURL = downloadedURL {

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: downloadedURL)    // in this approach this line crashes the code and the bottom print not executes
                print("\(#line):<\(data.base64EncodedString())>")
            } catch {
                print("\(#line):<\(error.localizedDescription)>")
            }
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

in both cases the crash message in console is:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

and the fatal error is this:

```
Thread 5: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=12 MB, unused=0x0)
```

I will appreciate any idea or suggestion about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use a download task instead of a data task.

Comment: Have you seen all of my code? I‘ve used download task in second approach

Comment: Oops - I didn't scroll down far enough. The download task is the correct approach. The problem is trying to load too much data into memory. Don't try to load the whole file, it's too large.

Comment: I want to attach that mp4 as attachment for a notification, can you show some code?